# Suppose W = span(V) $ \subseteq $ $R^5 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose W = $ span\{w1,w2,w3,w4\}$ = span
$ \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}, 
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1  \end{pmatrix},
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3  \end{pmatrix}\  
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}\right\} $
$ \subseteq $ $R^5 .$

The RREF of $ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0  & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 3 & 1   \end{pmatrix}$ is $ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \end{pmatrix}.$

**Is the dim(W) = 3?**

When I did row reduction, I found that w1, w2, w3 except w4 can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors $ w_i$  in the set excluding itself, (e.g w2 expressed as a linear combination of w1,3,4), doesn't this mean that t**he number of vectors in the basis is 1? So, why would the dim(W) = 3?** Please correct me if I am wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion here. Consider, for instance, the vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(1,1,0)$ from $\Bbb R^3$. Each of them is a linear combination of the other two. However, they span $\{(x,y,0)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}$, which is $2$-dimensional, not $1$-dimensional.

Your case is similar: the dimension of $W$ is $3$, not $1$.

A vector space $V$ distinct from $\{0\}$ is $1$-dimensional if and only if, given $v,w\in V\setminus\{0\}$, there is some scalar $\lambda$ such that $v=\lambda w$. That's clearly not what happens with $W$.